# How to suggest only single words but index phrases

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, spell-checking

I am having troubles right now. I am using ShingleAnalyzerWrapper to index phrases. But I need the SpellChecker to suggest me only single words.

How can i index phrases but search for both phrases and single words with SpellChecker?

Please, give some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this constructor, for your [ShingleAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleAnalyzerWrapper.html#ShingleAnalyzerWrapper%28org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

```
ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(Analyzer defaultAnalyzer, 
                       int minShingleSize, 
                       int maxShingleSize, 
                       String tokenSeparator, 
                       boolean outputUnigrams, 
                       boolean outputUnigramsIfNoShingles)
```

passing `true` as the fifth argument (outputUnigrams).  This will index all single tokens regardless of what you minShingleSize is.  If your current minShingleSize is 2, you could just lower that to 1 to achieve the same result.